# JNI - transfer from jstring to byte, from byte to string issue

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I have a problem with converting in JNI.

In C++ I'm creating some cipher using AES (Library CryptoPP). I'm converting result to string and returning it. This is how the code getting the string looks like:

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_example_androidake_MutualAuthenticateChip_prepareEncryptionCPP
(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jboolean hmm, jboolean jinit) {

    string encryption= mac->EncryptCertKey();

    jbyteArray returns = env->NewByteArray(encryption.size());
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(returns, 0, encryption.length(), (jbyte*) encryption.c_str());

    return returns;
};
```

Above string is converting to jbyteArray which is returned. First I wanted just return string using

```
env->NewStringUTF(encryption.c_str());
```

but the application has been crashing. I think it is caused by content of variable 'encryption'. I'm using env->NewStringUTF(encryption.c_str()); in other functions, where returned string is for example just a number or something like that.

Then in Java I'm doing conversion from byte to string:

```
byte[] cipher = mac_A.prepareEncryptionCPP(true, true);
string cipher_str =  new String(cipher);
```

And I'm putting that string again to the C++ object and compare old cipher with the cipher which is sent from Java:

```
//Java
boolean result = mac_A.compareEncryption(true, cipher);
//JNI
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_androidake_MutualAuthenticateChip_compareEncryption
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject thisObj, jboolean jinit, jstring cipher){
    bool init = jinit;
    bool result;

    jsize length = env->GetStringUTFLength(cipher);
    const char *inCStr_ek = env->GetStringUTFChars(cipher, 0);
    string s(inCStr_ek, length);

    result = mac->CompareCipher(s);

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(cipher, inCStr_ek);
    return result;
};
```

Comparing in C++ :

```
bool MyClass::CompareCipher(std::string cipher_2){
    if(cipher == cipher_2){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And it always returns false. I do not know what I'm doing wrong. I've even sent this cipher from Java to C++ and take it back to Java and the strings are equals, but in C++ side are not.

Comment: "I'm converting [the encrypted] result to string." This is already a mistake, unless you are hex-encoding or base64-encoding it first. String is not a container for binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your java side code you have

```
byte[] cipher = mac_A.prepareEncryptionCPP(true, true);
boolean result = mac_A.compareEncryption(true, cipher);
```

`compareEncryption` jni function is defined with jstring , not jbytearray.

So from JNI side you are sending a byte array to java, and from java side you send back the same byte array to native side (but uses jstring in call), but then you are using `env->GetStringUTFChars(cipher, 0)` which converts that byte array into a modified UTF-8 string, so its technically not that same byte array anymore.

if you need strings do the conversions in java side, and just use with same plain byte arrays between jni and java. [See this for string encoding issues](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#UTF_8_and_UTF_16_strings)  in Android JNI.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake in rewriting code here. I'm using boolean result = mac_A.compareEncryption(true, cipher_str); I will check tomorrow your link.

Comment: that string is being converted by `GetStringUTFChars` to modified-utf8. I would consider sending in jbytearray instead from java side, so you have the same byte array on jni side for comparison.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I send byte to the comparing function is everything fine. I had some problems with changing this byte array to String Base64 then back this String to byte array and only then send this byte array to comparing function (this is just for test) but I solved it. Thanks again.